# Ng-repeat within ng-repeat and radio button

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

Ng-model is causing an issue with two ng-repeat. Clicking on one radio button of one row affecting others row with same ng-model value.

```
 <table class="data-table -dark-header">
<tr>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Read Only</th>
    <th>Read Write</th>
    <th>Admin</th>
    <th>Super Admin</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in wrapper_User track by user.id">
        <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
            <td ng-repeat="groupsWithinCompany in wrapper_Group | orderBy:'id'">
                <div>

                    <label class="radio-label">
                        <span class="custom-radio">
                          <input type="radio" name="{{user.id}}" ng-value="groupsWithinCompany.id"  ng-model="user.group.id" />

                        </span>
                      </label>

                </div>
            </td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: please post example of `wrapper_User ` and `wrapper_Group`

Comment: Maxim What would be solution for this. Both array are coming from server end.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the problem is in your data structure.

Following example works:

```
$scope.wrapper_User = [
    {id:1, firstName: "firstName1", lastName: "lastName1", group:{id:10}},
    {id:2, firstName: "firstName2", lastName: "lastName2", group:{id:20}},
    {id:3, firstName: "firstName3", lastName: "lastName3", group:{id:30}},
    {id:4, firstName: "firstName4", lastName: "lastName4", group:{id:40}}
    ];

    $scope.wrapper_Group = [
      {id:10},
      {id:20},
      {id:30},
      {id:40}
      ];
```

---

Be sure that group ids match

<kbd>[DEMO in PLunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VtAtyaUI8wHWOJ7Sr7Al?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Array from my sever are circular in nature maybe that is causing an issue. Static array are working fine. Any solution for that. Thanks for plunkr.

Comment: @PiyushKalra post your jSON comes from Server, if you want us to help you